# Is there a VBA worksheet function that will allow me to do a two layer search?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, worksheet-function

Is there any formula that I can use to make a double-layer search?

I want to be able to gather whatever information on the third column that meets two criteria.

1. It has to be one location (in this case, Indonesia)
2. It has to be a particular industry (FMCG)

Example here:
[image]

Comment: Please, show us what you tried by your own.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can do this with MATCH or SUMIFS if you are searching for a number

Comment: Should the combination be unique? I mean, only one such combination may exist? What about the column "Industry Size" for many combinations? Should the amount be added, or this is not possible and combination is unique?

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi, I wasn't even sure how to approach this. I thought about doing a count of the country, then setting the range as, in this example, "C10:C" 10 + count and using the vlookup function, but unless there's a function that I don't know about, I would have to manually code for each country's starting cell. 


I would need to find, for instance, Indonesia's FCMG if I have an excel macro that inputs Indonesia and FMCG.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I'm trying to get the Industry Size cell value. So, for instance, Industry Size for Indonesia's FCMG.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who contributed! I really appreciate the help I received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If industry size is a numeric field, you got 2 options to get this. If not, then you can do it only with MATCH and INDEX

With MATCH/INDEX: `=INDEX($C$2:$C$11;MATCH(F17&G17;A2:A11&B2:B11;0))`

With SUMIFS: `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$11;$A$2:$A$11;F18;$B$2:$B$11;G18)`

Depending on your Excel version, the MATCH formula may need to be introduced as an array formula so you must introduce it pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: I'm sorry for leaving this piece of information out, but is there a way that I can pick the column like in vlookup if there were more columns with information to choose from?

Thank you by the way! If there's no way then I can just make an index match for whichever I need. There are only 5 additional columns anyways.  

Really appreciate you taking your time to help out a newbie like me

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. I realized I didn't input anything into the column portion of the index function. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a VBA solution, please use the next function:

```
Function extractIndSize(strCountry As String, strInd As String, rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, arr
    arr = rng.value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = strCountry And arr(i, 2) = strInd Then
            extractIndSize = arr(i, 3): Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

It can be tested using the next way:

```
Sub testExtractIndustrySize()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastR)
  
  MsgBox extractIndSize("Indonesia", "FMCG", rng)
End Sub
```

The function can also be called (as UDF) from a cell, using the next formula:

```
 =extractIndSize(E2,F2,A2:C11)
```

Where in "E2" the country name must be introduced, in "F2" the industry name and the third parameter is the range to be processed (selected with the cursor),,,